# Earth map generator alternative to Basemap

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

Since Basemap is deprecated, is there any other alternative such cartopy, geopandas, etc.. that can generate this beautiful maps (and not just the contour-type) that I got with Basemap with different projections? (hopefully that works offline too)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this blogpost: https://thomasguymer.co.uk/blog/2018/2018-01-15/ it provides a good solution to replace the default background map of cartopy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does cartopy’s [`ax.stock_image()`](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/matplotlib/intro.html) do the trick? It looks ver similar to what you’re shooting for.

For example, to plot a globe using a geostationary projection:

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Geostationary())
ax.stock_img()
plt.show()
```

[image]
Check out the guide to projections to get more projection options: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/crs/projections.html#cartopy-projections